# Filtering a list by the different elements of two python sets

Tags: python, pandas, list, filter, set

In the example below I am trying to filter a list by the elements that are different in the setB and setC. I can´t see how to correct the error.

```
import pandas as  pd

listA = [ 10, 20, 30 , 40 , 50 , 60 , 70, 80, 90, 100]
setB = { 10, 30, 50 , 70, 80, }
setC = { 10, 30, 50}

listA[:, list(setB)[setB not in setC]]
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 listA[:, list(setB)[setB not in setC]]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Do you know what your output is supposed to look like? Maybe you want a symmetric difference: `[*filter((setB ^ setC).__contains__, listA)]  `

Comment: Could you add your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve what you are seeking with the below:

```
listA = [i for i in listA if i not in setB and i not in setC]
```

You will get:

```
listA = [20, 40, 60, 90, 100]
```